# Grab one or two words IF capitalised after a pattern and match the result with another list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to extract unique names with titles such as Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron from text and match it with another list. I struggle to get the right result and hope the community can help me. Thanks!

```
import re
def get_names(text):
    # find nobel titles and grab it with the following name
    match = re.compile(r'(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron) ([A-Z][a-z]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)')
    names = list(set(match.findall(text)))
    # remove duplicates based on the index in tuples
    names_ = list(dict((v[1],v) for v in sorted(names, key=lambda names: names[0])).values())
    names_lst = list(set([' '.join(map(str, name)) for name in names_]))
    return names_lst

text = 'Baroness Firstname Surname and Baroness who is also known as Lady Anothername and Lady Surname or Lady Firstname.'
names_lst = get_names(text)
print(names_lst)
```

Which now yields:`['Baroness Firstname Surname']`

Desired output: `['Baroness Firstname Surname', 'Lady Anothername']` but NOT `Lady Surname` or `Lady Firstname`

Then I need to match the result with this list:

```
other_names = ['Firstname Surname', 'James', 'Simon Smith']
```

and drop the element `'Firstname Surname'` from it because it matches the first name and surname of the Baroness in 'the desired output'.

Comment: Firstly, you did provide an example, but you ought to explain a bit further exactly what you intend to accomplish, especially regarding the bit towards the end: "I need to match the result with this list" ... "and drop the element" ... Explaining why you need to do this will clear up the question a lot. Also, how much data are we talking about here? Do you really only need to match those few examples you gave? (Baroness, Lady, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you the following solution:

```
import re

def get_names(text):
    # find nobel titles and grab it with the following name
    match = re.compile(r'(Lord|Baroness|Lady|Baron) ([A-Z][a-z]+)[ ]?([A-Z][a-z]+)?')
    names = list(match.findall(text))
    # keep only the first title encountered
    d = {}
    for name in names:
        if name[0] not in d:
            d[name[0]] = ' '.join(name[1:3]).strip()
    return d

text = 'Baroness Firstname Surname and Baroness who is also known as Lady Anothername and Lady Surname or Lady Firstname.'
other_names = ['Firstname Surname', 'James', 'Simon Smith']

names_dict = get_names(text)
print(names_dict)
#  {'Baroness': 'Firstname Surname', 'Lady': 'Anothername'}
print([' '.join([k,v]) for k,v in names_dict.items()])
# ['Baroness Firstname Surname', 'Lady Anothername']

other_names_dropped = [name for name in other_names if name not in names_dict.values()]
print(other_names_dropped)
# ['James', 'Simon Smith']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It'll definitely help me move forward but I need to drop the matching name 'Firstname Surname' from the 'other_names' list and not the other way round.

Comment: I had not understood, but now it seems clear. I updated my post. OK for you, now ?

Comment: Thank you! Happy Friday!